# Permanently enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm running mysql 5.7.17 on Windows 7 and I've found its configuration to be different than when I run from the docker image. More specifically, the docker image adds the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, which the windows installation doesn't by default. I would like to add it in windows too (permanently, not just for the session). I've tried with this options:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"
```

and

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```

In `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my-default.ini` (that's the only file the installation creates, but it is told in the comments not to edit it), `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini` and `C:\Windows\my.ini`. When I execute `mysql --help` I get this output:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   C:\windows\my.ini C:\windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\M ySQL Server 5.7\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL
>   Server 5.7\my.cnf

I've got nothing related in `C:\`.

But the server seems not to pick the sql mode. When I query for `SELECT @@sql_mode` and `SELECT @@global.sql_mode` I only get `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

From [the Mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html):

> On Windows, MySQL Installer interacts with the user and creates a file named my.ini in the base installation directory as the default option file. If you install on Windows from a Zip archive, you can copy the my-default.ini template file in the base installation directory to my.ini and use the latter as the default option file.

But again, I only got `my-default.ini` created.

Comment: 5.7.5+ uses `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (and some modes more) by default, so you could just remove that option from your config files to enable that mode. You seem to have some config files somewhere you are unaware of, since the current sql mode doesn't fit any of your values. I would try to tidy up your config files and just use one file. You can add more if you need to share options across installations. Do you have a second mysql installation? Maybe that one is running, check the base dir there too. Also, you need to restart your server to make the server take notice of the config change.

Comment: @Solarflare, no more MySql installations and the one running is the one that belongs to the path I'm looking to. However, I had a MariaDb installation before, that could be causing this mess?

Comment: No, if it is is not running, it should not cause harm, my idea was that sometimes the running server (service) is not the one in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\`, so you might miss the actually used config file (in the installation directory). Did you restart the server after changing the file? It's strange that your sql mode doesn't fit your config file at all, that's why I suspect you missed some config file.